# How to check whether a SELECT query is Successful?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Well i am new to SQL and i have just read that it's a good practice that stored procedures always return a value determining whether the query inside the procedure has been executed successfully or not.
So i have a simple stored procedure with a select statement in it and i want to return 1 if it gets executed and return -1 if it does not.
Can you please tell me how to write that condition in SQL?
If it matters my database is MS SQL Server.
Thank you.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myTest   
AS  
BEGIN  
    SELECT FirstName,LastName FROM Employees  
    RETURN 1 (If execution is successfull)  
    RETURN -1(If execution is not successfull)  
END;
```

Comment: Explain better about "successfull". If you have 0 rows is KO, if you have > 0 rows is OK?

Comment: RETURN is normally used on UDF (user defined function). With SP you can use output parameter

Comment: What is the purpose of such a stored procedure? Checking if select was "successful" (by the way what is it? any select will be successful if there are appropriate columns in table) but returning 1 instead of selected values looks meaningless...

Comment: If by successful you mean successful execution, then a try-catch block is all you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an output parameter to return the success status along with Try..Catch blocks

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myTest 
 @Result INT OUTPUT  
AS  
BEGIN  
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  BEGIN TRY
     SELECT FirstName,LastName FROM Employees  
     SET @Result = 1;
  END TRY  

  BEGIN CATCH
     SET @Result = 0;
  END CATCH

END;
```

Answer (score 3):

@@ROWCOUNT this command helpful,means effective rows number.

```
return @@ROWCOUNT
```

you just need do this. if result > 0, success, if not ,fail.

Answer (score 2):

```
Create Procedure testproc
as 
select * from  tabletest
if @@error<>0
 return -1
else 
 return 0
```

This should do good, if the select statement fails then the @@error variable will be set to some value, hence procedure will return -1 value.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Depend on your stored procedure logic. If you know the count of rows, you can use     @@ROWCOUNT variable. If your code can raise exception you can use BEGIN TRY...BEGIN CATCH block.

Answer (score 0):

To find out whether there are no matching rows exist you can use 
  **NOT EXISTS**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myTest   
AS  
BEGIN  
IF NOT EXISTS(select FirstName,LastName FROM Employees)
BEGIN
PRINT 'No Match Found'
END
```