# How to check if a command has executed successfully inside a procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Let's say I have this procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE CallsChange
    @ID int,
    @CS int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO [ctlCalls] ([InsertDate])
    VALUES (GETDATE())

    UPDATE [ctlOrders]
    SET [DeliverymanID] = NULL,
        [CallId] = (SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()),
        [CurrentStatus] = 1
    WHERE ID = @ID 
END
```

What I want to know is: if there is a SQL Server variable that returns value if after update something has changed in database or not? In other words: if update has been run successfully

Comment: `Select @@ROWCOUNT` will return the number of rows affected by previous DML operation

Comment: Here you [go](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34490531/6611487) buddy

Comment: Aside: You can use an [`OUTPUT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause to get any data from the rows (Note plural.), e.g. identity column values for newly inserted rows. `OUTPUT` can be used with `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `MERGE` and provides access to both _before_ and _after_ values in the case of `UPDATE`. A tool well worth having in your pocket.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Print statements to check if a command has executed successfuly inside a procedure..

**EX:**

```
create proc usp_test
as
begin

insert into t1
select 2

Print 'Insert completed'

update t
set id=1

print 'update completed'

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE CallsChange
    @ID int,
    @CS int,
    @Output varchar(10) = '' OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO [ctlCalls] ([InsertDate])
    VALUES (GETDATE())

    UPDATE [ctlOrders]
    SET [DeliverymanID] = NULL,
        [CallId] = (SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()),
        [CurrentStatus] = 1
    WHERE ID = @ID 
   SET @Output = @@ROWCOUNT       
   SELECT  'Updated ' + @Output + ' records'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use print statement in stored procedure as mentioned in above answer.
2. whenever you execute a stored procedure, the message box will appear how many rows were updated.
   3 . Since you are updating with scope identity the table will always be updated with a new value. it it is not updated, you can check in trigger by using INSERTED or DELETED tables